# Select all data from all but 2 SQL tables in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select all rows from all tables except for 2 tables in SQL for use in PHP calculations. I am trying run the follow query:

```
SELECT MovieID, Rating FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'moviedb' AND TABLE_NAME <> ('movies', 'users');
```

This is returning "`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'MovieID' in 'field list'`" in SQL.

All tables except 'movies' and 'users' have identical columns but varying data and amounts of data (some are all null).

I have tried using EXCEPT and it doesn't seem to work on the version of SQL we are running. It's for a school project on a school server so I have to use the version available.

Comment: First why would you want to do that for every table in DB?  Second, you can not do that, you can build your list of tables from the query above, and then loop through those and build dynamic Select statements to select the data from each table that way.

Comment: When a user creates an account a table is created with MovieIDs and what they rating them (Rating). We are also storing our 'movies' and 'users' tables in the DB so we need to exclude them. I'll try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you need to redesign your DB.  When the user creates an account, have a lookup table that has UserID, MovieID, and Rating.  Then tie to that table by the user who rated the movies (instead of having a table for every user).  That will get out of hand very quickly and make it impossible to maintain if you need to do anything on the tables.  Cleaning up data, schema changes, etc.  If you have in one table it will run much faster, and be easy to maintain.